# Indeed XML Feed Status Check

Tags: xml, laravel, jobs

Am trying to integrate indeed and post jobs through **XML feed** in laravel (6). I followed the indeed official documentation which linked below

https://techdocs.indeedeng.io/direct-employer-integration-with-indeed

As per the documentation I did the following steps

1. Created a xml file with the standard of indeed and hosted in public server
2. Created an API token from indeed and attached that to xml which I created
3. Created a callback function once some one apply to posted job.

I did everything properly, unfortunately I couldn't get my job in indeed search result. I would like to know is there any API to check the job has been posted successfully or is there any error. I  gone through their documentation I couldn't find any API like that. If any body know how to check status  of xml feed jobs please let me know

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you let me know on which public server, you have hosted the XML file?